# Can't get Fullscreen from manifest on Firefox

Tags: android, firefox, mobile, fullscreen, manifest

WRT: -[Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest#Browser_compatibility)

After adding to homescreen, I am unable to lose any of the browser Chrome with Firefox on Android. (Samsung Galaxy S7)

Chrome and Opera are fine, Samsung browser degrades to supporting "standalone" but Firefox still has the URL, buttons and so on.

How can this still not be supported on Firefox when they had this functionality years ago with their App Store and web-app INSTALL functionality?

Comment: This should be fully implemented in firefox 58, it's about time! I'm still using chrome on my android only to create proper PWA.